# Android density and resolution and their layout

Tags: java, android

How would you separate a layout implementation for 320x480 (180dpi density) resolution and a a 480x800 (233 dpi density) resolution? It seems that when I create a layout-mdpi and layout-hdpi they both read from the first one.

Comment: How do you know that both layouts come from the same folder(`layout-mdpi`(the second device shouldn't take the layout from `layout-mdpi` if you supply `layout-hdpi` as 233dpi is out of the zone of mdpi))? Have you tried setting a tag for one of the views in both folders and then see in code which one you get based on that tag?

Answer (score 0):

hello  you r making wrong folder u can make 4 folder for layout(xml) and 3 folders for images

```
  For layout 4 Folders are :
    i) layout-small
    ii) layout
    iii) layout-large
    iv) layout-xlarge
 For Images 3 Folders 
   i) drawable-ldpi
   ii) drawable-mdpi
   iii) drawable-hdpi
```

Answer (score 0):

For 320X480 resolution make Layout-normal ,drawable-mdpi

and for 480X800 resolution make Layout-large,drawable-mdpi folders

Comment: It again takes the one in layout-normal for both devices.

Comment: yes but try to modify your xml as per your requirement in seperate folder ,then check.

Comment: yes I did that. They have different values for some of the views width.

Comment: then is there any effect on both devices ?

Comment: as i said, both devices use the layout in layout-normal.